# Two table SQL query based on a field within the query while pulling from another table

Tags: sql, powershell, ms-access-2007

Okay this may sound a bit weird but it is what I have to work with.

I have a special installer that will be utilizing powershell to do a query to an access 2007 database

The first table is a list of programs.  One column in the table is prog_pre  which indicates that the program has something that must be installed before it can be installed

the pre_req table has a column called prog_id which is the unique ID for the particular program that has a requires another program to be installed first.
It also has the prog_pre column which references the unique id in the program table.

What I want to do is when I preform a query like

```
 Select * 
 from program_table 
 WHERE ID = '3'
```

program 3  which is barware has a pre_req  so I want it to also loop through the pre_req table grab the IDs of the pre required programs and also add it to the query.

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with simply preforming two queries?

#### program table

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
ID  prog_name       prog_version    prog_pre
1   Access          2007             No
2   Acrobat         2012 pro         No
3   barware         2012             Yes
4   Fooware         2012             No
5   foomaker        2012             No
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### pre_req table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
id  prog_id     prog_pre
1   3           4
2   3           5
```

```
The desired results would be an array as follows
3   barware         2012             Yes
4   Fooware         2012             No
5   foomaker        2012             No
```

As the field prog_pre was yes, it also included the two prog_pre progam ids listed in the pre_Req table

Comment: It would help for you to show what your desired outcome is in the form of a table (like you've shown your source).

Comment: If there's a maximum number of levels, you can do it by hand.  Otherwise, you're stuck with program code.  I've seen mention that Access doesn't support recursive queries, which is what you want.

Comment: A DB join should work. Need to see  your required output before can spend time on solving this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a comment made by X-Zero

> Blockquote If there's a maximum number of levels, you can do it by hand. Otherwise, you're stuck with program code. I've seen mention that Access doesn't support recursive queries, which is what you want.- X-Zero

I did some further research and found that what I wanted was indeed a recursive query.  I also found that X-Zero was correct.  Access does not support Recursive queries.

[Is it possible to create a recursive query in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763016/is-it-possible-to-create-recursive-query-in-access)

Thank you for your assistance X-Zero