# MS Access select query inside another select query for selecting another field value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't think of any better way.

What I am trying to do is grab some data from table where the field `childitem="NL"` and the complex part in selecting fields to show is that, I need to make new field `Consumption` but this field value will be same `childqty` but when the field `processname` first 2 character is *SC*, I need to make the Consumption value to a `childqty` of another field: current `father` (4-SCF-329...[id:30]) is `child` to another `father` (4-FCM-3290...[id:17]) which is indeed `child` to another `father` (4-MCS-329....[id:21])

My Query:

```
SELECT tblBom.processname AS Process,
    tblBom.child AS [SAP Code],
    tblBom.childname AS Material,
    iif(LEFT(tblBom.processname,2)="SC", 
        (SELECT childqty FROM tblBom WHERE tblBom.child like (SELECT father FROM tblBom WHERE child Like tblBom.father)), 
        tblBom.childqty
    ) AS consumption,
    tblBom.childrate AS [Landed Rate],
    tblBom.childrate * tblBom.childqty As RATE
FROM tblBom
WHERE tblBom.childitem Like "NL";
```

I want the `tblBom.father` last in the 5th line of code to be the main Queries father. Is there a way to make it as variable somewhere or any way. If I change it to "4-SCF*" that will work.

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YBtp.png)

[Excel Detailed View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c29fd.png)

- Orange: Condition checking for word "SC"
- Yellow: The value that need to be replaced
- Green: The value that will be placed on the yellow
- ReddishPink: The path to Green value for query

[Desired OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqu27.png)

Comment: Maybe: `LIKE [enter some value] & "*"`. Or reference a form control for variable input.

Comment: The thing is, I can't predict what will be in field `father`. All I want is get the `father` of main SELECT query and pass it to sub sub SELECT query.

Comment: still too confusing for me.  Please show desired query output and all important parts of source table.  In particular we need to see the full values of father.

Comment: Can I share you the table as an xlsx file, I am getting this table from a another complicated big table. So the values in tblBom will change when I run the main query. That is why I need to lie on the complex 2 sub queries inside Main query here

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/x4JXoH  : First sheet the tblBom, second sheet is what is the output am looking for. I have highlighted some cells with color, where I am using query.

Comment: Cannot attach files in SO and many will not download from external source. Might want to post in a forum that does allow attaching files.

Comment: So which forum to go ?

Comment: Look at accessforums.net, utteraccess, accessworld

Comment: I have included the table image in excel view for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

My solution requires two calculated fields and two queries.  The calculated fields are UltimateFather and consumption.  we require two queries because the problem doesn't guarantee that a child's father has a value of childitem like "NL".  Hence we can't throw out any data before calculating each child's UltimateFather.  Ultimate Father is based on adding the public function GetUltimateFather to a code module.  Getting the UltimateFather is a recursive problem so see here for commentary on recursive functions in queries:
[Is it possible to create a recursive query in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763016/is-it-possible-to-create-a-recursive-query-in-access)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
'calculated fields
UltimateFather: GetUltimateFather([child])
consumption: IIf([processname] Like ("SC*"),DLookUp("childqty","tblBom","father = '" & [UltimateFather] & "'"),[childqty])
```

```
Public Function GetUltimateFather(childid As String) As String
Dim currentchild, hasfather As String
currentchild = childid
'string variables make sure to escape and delimit strings properly'
hasfather = Nz(DLookup("father", "tblBom", "child = '" & currentchild & "'"), "")
If hasfather = "" Then
GetUltimateFather = currentchild
Else
GetUltimateFather = GetUltimateFather(hasfather) 'get next father in chain
End If
End Function
```